# Jquery Jplayer Dynamic Playlist

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am having trouble figuring out on how to force the Jplayer to read songs from 
a dynamic asp.net liberal list?

Currently I have this for bringing a list of songs from the database:

```
<div class="jp-playlist">
<ul><asp:Literal ID="ltRadio" runat="server" /></ul>
</div>
```

The code below from the [JPlayer](http://jplayer.org/) demonstrates on how to add hardcoded songs to a playlist:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

new jPlayerPlaylist({
     jPlayer: "#jquery_jplayer",
     cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_1"
}, [
{
   title: "Cro Magnon Man",
   mp3: "http://www.jplayer.org/audio/mp3/TSP-01-Cro_magnon_man.mp3",
   oga: "http://www.jplayer.org/audio/ogg/TSP-01-Cro_magnon_man.ogg"
}
], {
     swfPath: "js",
     supplied: "oga, mp3",
     wmode: "window"
});
});
```

The question is how do I add songs from my 'Literal' list into the playlist?

Comment: Do you know that playlist functionality is currently supported? I see a SetMedia function but it doesn't look like there's next/previous. You may have to do some coding to extend the player

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well finally solved the problem. I was converting the JSon into a string which was not required.

Instead I loop through the JSon Object array and add it to the playlist.

```
/*Create an empty JSon array*/ 
var jsonobj = [];

/*Loop through a given list and push it into a JSon array*/
jQuery('ul.RadioList li a').each(function (index) {
       var mp3 = jsonobj.push({ 'mp3': jQuery(this).attr('href') });
       var title = [];
       title.push(jQuery(this).text());
       jsonobj[mp3 - 1]['title'] = title;
});

var cssSelector = {
       jPlayer: "#jquery_jplayer",
       cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_1"
};
/*An Empty Playlist*/
var playlist = []; 
   var options = {
       swfPath: "./js",
       supplied: "mp3"
};
var myPlaylist = new jPlayerPlaylist(cssSelector, playlist, options);
/*Loop through the JSon array and add it to the playlist*/ 
for (i = 0; i < jsonobj.length; i++) {
      myPlaylist.add(jsonobj[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simple do

```
myPlaylist = new jPlayerPlaylist({
        jPlayer: "#mediaPlayer",
        cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container"
    }, playList //JSON object
    , {
        swfPath: "dist/jplayer",
        supplied: "webmv, ogv, m4v, oga, mp3",
        useStateClassSkin: true
    });
```

and you JSON object can be a collection of following element

```
playList.push(
          {
            'm4v': fileURL,
             'title': "File Title,
          }
);
```